# Display content of a text file as combo box option

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to read content of a .txt file, loop through the lines & display them as multiselect/ options with combobox. I have 0 knowledge in html, css & js. Please help.

This is what i have built, after googling. But I don't need an i-frame. I need multi select options.

```
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<head>
   <title>Trigger</title>
      <style> 

        #target { 
            width: 300px; 
            height: 200px; 
            overflow-y: auto; 
            overflow-x: auto; 
            resize: both; 
            position: relative; 
            z-index: 2; 
        } 

        iframe { 
            width: 100%; 
            height: 100%; 
            border: auto; 
        } 
    </style> 
</head>

<body>

<h1 style="background-color:MediumSeaGreen; border:2px solid Black; font-family:verdana;">Trigger Page</h1>
<p style="font-family:verdana;" >Please select from the below list:</p>

<iframe id='iframe' src = 'D:/allStories.txt' onload='readfile()'> </iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

I am expecting multiselect list

Comment: Do you want to read a text file on the server with JS?

Comment: I want to read text file on my local machine & display the content in above mentioned format on localhost:8080/page. Html